# Rattling noise that goes away when braking?

Tags: brakes, noise, suspension, chrysler, town-and-country

Ever since my father had his last brake job on his 2008 Chrysler Town and Country, a very noticeable rattling noise appeared coming from the back right side of the van.

I was thinking that it was a suspension issue because the noise is heard whenever the van is driven over a bump or small pothole. So I was thinking maybe a worn bushing or strut or something loose. But then my father showed me that when the brakes are pressed even slightly while driving on a bumpy road or a pothole, there is no noise?

What are some possible issues that could be causing this?

What should I check?

Already checked the bushings and they seem fine.

Comment: I'd say that if it goes away if any brake is applied, it's something in the brakes. Regardless of what's causing it, if it happened right after a shop was working on your brakes, I'd suggest you bring it back to them and have them remedy it since it was likely a result of the work they did. I'm guessing you have drum brakes in the back (or at least a drum parking brake). If you wanted to look for yourself, I'd pull off the drums and see if anything looks wrong like a loose spring or something.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback! And no, there are calipers in the back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a loose caliper or sticky guide pin.  Take them all apart and really grease them replace the boots as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Missing brake pad hardware would cause this type of rattle that goes away during braking.

The brake shims or "brake pad fitting kit" might not have been fitted during the last brake job. They should be replaced with each brake job but reusing the old ones if they are in good condition shouldn't create this noise.

Comment: i checked it out and it looks like the last person that did the brakes on my father's car put the wrong brakes in the caliper...the brakes in the right rear appear to be the front brakes instead of the rear ones, like theyre supposed to be. Because the front ones are smaller just by a bit, theyre bouncing around in the caliper making the noise. Thank you everyone who took the time to write something on here to help.